# Multiple Aurelia apps on one page

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, aurelia

As there isn't much information about Aurelia framework I got stuck with these 2 questions.

1. Is it possible to create multiple Aurelia apps on single page and
   how this can be achieved?
2. Alternatively is there a way to call out single application templates in 2 different places outside the main app container?

   - For example I want to use Aurelia SPA in CMS system and call it out in different elements like header, main container and aside container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, just add two elements to the page with an `aurelia-app` attribute.

Here's an example: https://gist.run?id=2d310abbbea337fb5f6d110ec807f7d2

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Aurelia</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div aurelia-app="main1">
      <h1>Loading...</h1>
    </div>
    <div aurelia-app="main2">
      <h1>Loading...</h1>
    </div>
    ... 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Problem in my application was actually that I hadn't refer to correct root file in

`aurelia.start().then(a => a.setRoot('applicationrootfile'));` but thanks alot for the answer!

Comment: @jeremy-danyow how does this responds to changes in the url? If the browser url changes to an url which is only valid for app `main1` but not valid for `main2` then how would the `main2` part of the page would react?