# Data moving between multiple Aurelia apps on one page

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, aurelia

Based on question [Multiple Aurelia apps on one page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33473457/multiple-aurelia-apps-on-one-page), is there a way in Aurelia to make two apps on same page to working asynchronously, which is similar to Aurelia `.two-way` method for two different view models in view.

For example:

In app A I use `.post` method with `aurelia-http-client` to pass `this.data = {"data": this.item};` where `item` is bound to text input. In return I get `containerId` from API. Now in app B I want to use the same `containerId` with `.get` method for getting `data` posted in app A.

Later I would like to use app A and app B asynchronously with `.put` method which means whenever I update data using app A it will be updated automatically in app B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could create a "shared state" module (or modules) and import them as-needed.

## [Here's a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZWjLFm?p=preview)

Here's the code:

**shared-state.js**

```js
export var sharedState = {
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: 'bar',
  baz: 'baz'
};
```

**app1.js**

```js
import {sharedState} from './shared-state';

export class App {
  name = 'App 1';
  state = sharedState;
}
```

**app2.js**

```js
import {sharedState} from './shared-state';

export class App {
  name = 'App 2';
  state = sharedState;
}
```