# Aurelia multiple apps in multiple pages

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm working on the first production release of a large site developed in PHP (Phalcon), MySQL & JQuery. It's not API based although there will be an API available for some things. The slightly dated stack is due to the fact that the project was first prototyped years ago and for reasons I won't bore you with, it's taken years to get to the production development stage.

I realise that hard page reloads are so last year, but they also make sense in an application of this scale when navigating to a different section that serves a different purpose. As it works at the moment, once you get to a section, it pretty much behaves like a single page app using hashed URLs and ajax to change the content in one or more containers etc. especially where SEO is not an issue. This is all currently done with JQuery which is starting to get a bit messy and unmaintainable. There's also features such as notifications in the nav bar etc that appear on every page on the site, again updated and displayed via ajax.

My expertise is in PHP. The same can not be said for Javascript! But it's clear that JQuery alone is not enough. I need a JS framework to handle templating/binding, local routing to a reasonable depth and http etc. with  an MV..? structure to better organise the JS side of things and keep it maintainable. I greatly disliked Angular 1 and quit learning it as soon as I found out that Angular 2 was about to come along with major breaking changes. I tried Angular 2 beta and although better, it just doesn't float my boat. I had previously stumbled upon Aurelia alpha and although I didn't have a chance to play with it, watching the vids and reading about it, it seemed like a very nice bit of gear - nice syntax, designed for the present and the future and so on. Now at version 1 beta there's more documentation and resources available to learn it, and I feel fairly comfortable jumping aboard early and using it in this project.

I'm pretty much aware of what Aurelia can do, and I have a lot to learn. However, my big stumbling block at the moment is figuring out how to structure it and incorporate it into this project.

**Integration**

1. Each section of the site will need different Aurelia apps
2. Multiple Aurelia apps may be needed per page
3. Some Aurelia apps will be required on all pages

I found an [article by Patrick Walters](http://patrickwalters.net/creating-multipage-apps-using-aurelia-2/) which seemed to explain how this could be done by naming the app when you call it on the element;
`<body aurelia-app="main" start="app">`

Then setting up a shared main.js with;

```
aurelia.start().then(a => {
  let start = a.host.attributes.start.value;
  a.setRoot(start);
});
```

That seemed to make sense so I tried it, but placing the call in a div instead of the body. That doesn't work as `host` can not be resolved to anything (my IDE told me that before I even ran it). We don't need hostname/port info here, so I presume the author means to replace `host` with the element? But how exactly?

Any further advice on integration like this would be much appreciated.

I have seen answers to similar questions on SO, but they do not seem to reuse `main.js` but duplicate it instead which doesn't seem right.

**Structure**

I played around with moving files with src to subdirectories to split things up into some clear structure. The only way I could get that to work was to add a named path for each in the config e.g. `"welcome*": "dist/welcome/welcome*",`. Is that the best/only way?

Comment: Hey, I'm curious if you found a satisfying solution in the end, something that would allow you to "group" common chunks of code..

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a right answer for your question. Only you are capable to decide which strategy fits better in your situation. As far as I can see, you can achieve this strategy with Aurelia. However, I'm not sure about the reusage of `main.js`.

You can load an aurelia app inside an specific tag using:

```
aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot('my-root', document.getElementById('some-element'));
```

If you want to load more than one app in the same page, you'd need 2 `main.js` files. This thread [Multiple Aurelia apps on one page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33473457/multiple-aurelia-apps-on-one-page) has a very useful example of two apps in the same page.

In my understanding, apps that share the same page should have one project structure, it means only one config.js, src folder, dist folder, etc. Apps that do not share the same page should have a different project structure, with a different config.js, src folder, dist folder (a different Aurelia version if necessary). That guarantees the independence of one app to another, preventing breaking changes.

Of course, that is only my opinion. You can wait for the aurelia guys for further instructions, they are always around.

Hope this helps!