# Move aurelia-app attribute to another html element?

Tags: html, aurelia

All the examples for aurelia seem to place the `aurelia-app` directive on the `<body>` element.

Can `aurelia-app` be placed on other html elements, rather than on `<body>`? If so, would there be a reason to avoid doing so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [official documentation](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.2.4/doc/article/app-configuration-and-startup) states:

> Simply place this on an HTML element and Aurelia's bootstrapper will
>   load an app.js and app.html, databind them together and inject them
>   into the DOM element on which you placed that attribute.

I tested this with:

```
<body>
  <div aurelia-app="app-window">
  </div>
  ...
</body>
```

and it does indeed appear to inject your aurelia app at that point:

[image]

What I don't know is if this is a good idea or not, i.e. if there going to be unforeseen problems by doing this.

Comment: No downside I know of, infact some plugins that attach themselves to the body would survive because aurelia won't clear them... this also allows you to have a standard page with an aurelia-app in a particular section.

Comment: This is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33473457/multiple-aurelia-apps-on-one-page of where you're not just restricted to the body tag...

Comment: This is as intended - by convention, overwrite the content in the body, unless the developer configures another node (convention over configuration in action!)